# ModelState errors not being displayed after changing Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nerddinner

I'm following the NerdDinner example on Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0 (I'm using the version of ASP.NET MVC that comes with VisualStudio 2015), and so far I was able to fix some little problems, but this one got me.

I have a model named Dinner, which is being passed to a view for an action called Create(). The view corresponding to Create is basically a form that asks for some information, and when it is submitted the page displays errors if there are any. The errors are communicated to the view through ModelState object.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Dinner dinner = new Dinner();
        return View(dinner);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Dinner d)
    {
        TryUpdateModel(d);
        if (d.isValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var violation in d.GetRuleViolations())
                ModelState.AddModelError(violation.PropertyName, violation.ErrorMessage);
            return View(d);
        }
    }
```

Create view looks something like this.

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.Dinner

...

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

...
```

This worked fine until I created a new model called DinnerFormViewModel to pass additional objects to Create view.

```
public class DinnerFormViewModel
{
    public Dinner Dinner
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DinnerFormViewModel() : this(new Dinner()) { }

    public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner d)
    {
        Dinner = d;
    }

    ... stuff ...
}
```

I updated the Create() method to make sure I was passing the correct model to the corresponding view.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Dinner dinner = new Dinner();
        return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));   // Updated line.
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DinnerFormViewModel d)   // Updated line.
    {
        TryUpdateModel(d);
        if (d.Dinner.isValid)   // Updated line.
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var violation in d.Dinner.GetRuleViolations())   // Updated line.
                ModelState.AddModelError(violation.PropertyName, violation.ErrorMessage);
            return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(d.Dinner));   // Updated line.
        }
    }
```

Also updated the view.

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel

...

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Dinner.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

...
```

The page functions as it should (valid form data is saved correctly), but when invalid information is submitted errors are not displayed on the page anymore. In the view file I checked the errors stored in ModelState and they were all there. There seems to be a disconnect between the ModelState and the form fields. I'm thinking the problem is the property names I am providing to ModelState.AddModelError() method, but I'm not sure about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you have a class instance property inside your model, if it's *null*, validation is not run on any of its properties. Second, your class instance property has a private setter, so the modelbinder will be unable to actually set it to anything, meaning it will always be null.

Long and short, the issue is the private setter.

Comment: I should have added the constructors for DinnerFormViewModel in the first place. (I updated the code above.) In DinnerFormViewMode class l am making sure that whenever it is instantiated either a Dinner object is passed or a new one is created. Well, actually in DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner d) I am not checking if d is null or not, but I think I always pass a non-null Dinner object to it. I'm still going to add a check to see if that ever happens. So, private setter should not be the problem (I tried making it public just in case, didn't work.)

Comment: Well it's still one problem. The modelbinder will only ever use the parameterless constructor, so it will only be able to set properties with post data which are public.